# Instantiate prefabs to a canvas at mouse coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a project I'm currently working on, I am having users click on an area for where they want to place things into the environment later on down the line. I'd like to visualize what they're placing with simple markers placed on the canvas, so that as they add and remove points the markers come and go as well.

I've found some resources on how to start, listing how to instantiate prefabs into the canvas, but it never seems to work for me. I feel it must have something to do with how I'm using coordinates but I'm not entirely sure.

```
public GameObject markerPrefab;
```

Then later on in another function

```
GameObject boatMarker = Instantiate(markerPrefab, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity);
boatMarker.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);
```

The code runs, and the prefabs do spawn into the scene, but they all appear in the top right hand corner of the canvas, all sort of one on top of the other. Any ideas what I've done wrong here? Also, while I don't want to ask you guys to write my code for me, any suggestions for a jumping point on how to remove specific instances of the prefab later down the line?

Comment: is your prefab a 2D gameobjet or 3D Gameobject ?

Comment: @QusaiAzzam For now it is just a button that does nothing, all I need is boxes to label where boats will be so it seemed to work best. Would something else work better for this?

Comment: is the canvas `screenspace overlay`?

Comment: @derHugo yes it is

Comment: Just to be sure .. you are speaking about a 2D app and not a VR/AR environment, right?

Comment: @derHugo this is not a vr application, correct, it is Unity-3d

Comment: .... yes but are you building for VR/AR or a e.g. topdown 2D app that will be executed on a PC or smartphone (2D Display?)

Comment: @derHugo oh I'm sorry I misunderstood the question, the latter option, it will be executed on a PC 2D display, not AR/VR. Sorry for the confusion, that's my bad.

Comment: @LordBaphelon sorry if the question was confusing. I just wanted to exlude that the usage of `Input.mousePosition` is the problem (in VR/AR it will always stay on `0,0` which is the upper left corner)

Answer (score 4):

The main issue I'ld say is that you are using [`SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) with the second parameter `false`

> If `true`, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the **same world space position**, rotation and scale as before.

In your case you **want** to keep the same world space position.

Since your canvas is `Screenspace overlay` its width and height (in Unity units) match exactly the display/window pixel width and height. Therefore when you do

```
GameObject boatMarker = Instantiate(markerPrefab, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

The object already **is** in the correct position. To visualize that I just gave it a cube as child so you see it spawns already where I clicked (you can't see the image yet beacuase it's not a child of a Canvas):

[image]

What happens if you pass in that `false` parameter to the `SetParent` is that it doesn't keep it's current worldspace position but instead keeps its current localPosition and moves to that relative position within its parent. Since it is a `Canvas` and your prefab probably also using a `RectTransform` the resulting position depends on a lot of things like the e.g. the pivot and anchor settings of the prefab's `RectTransform` but also e.g. the `Canvas Scaler` -> `Scale Factor`.

If your prefab e.g. is anchored on the center (usually the default) and you click exactly on the center of your window it will appear on the upper right corner instead.

[image]

Why?

1. you click at `(windowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2)`. So the prefab is originally spawned here
2. Than you use SetParent with `false` so it keeps that position but this time relative to the center of the Canvas

   => Center of canvas position is `(windowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2)` so adding the local prefab coordinates `(windowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2)` results in the final position `(WindowWidth, WindowHeight)` == upper right corner.

---

So you could fix that either by making the prefab beiing anchored on the lower left corner

[image]

or do not pass `false` as parameter to `SetParent`.

```
boatMarker.transform.SetParent(_canvas.transform);
```

you could actually then also do it in one single call

```
Instantiate(markerPrefab, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity, _canvas.transform);
```

---

Additionally you should not use `FindObjectWidthTag` again and again. I would rather only get it once or even reference it via the Inspector if possible:

```
public GameObject markerPrefab;

[SerializeField] private Canvas _canvas;

private void Awake()
{
    // If no canvas is provided get it by tag
    if (!_canvas) _canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       Instantiate(markerPrefab, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity, _canvas.transform);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! Anchoring it to the bottom left worked like a charm! I feel it worth mentioning however that removing the false value from the SetParent() made the markers disappear entirely

Answer (score 0):

Try This :
1- insert the button into the Canvas 
2- get a Gameobject reference for this button 
3- try this code after assigning your button to the button variable and the Game Canvas to the code Canvas variable, and it will work fine

```
    public GameObject refButton;
    public GameObject canvas;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject button = Instantiate(refButton, Input.mousePosition,Quaternion.identity);
            button.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, still the same issue with all of the buttons appearing in the top right hand corner of the canvas.

Comment: can you please delete your canvas and insert a new one then try it ! I just test the code, and it's working fine!

Comment: I added a new, fresh canvas to the scene and attached your code to that, and it still appears always in the top right hand corner, not exactly on the same spot though, there is some slight variation, but very little. Could it potentially have something to do with camera angles? My camera faces straight downwards.

Comment: use [ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) to get the point within your UI rect